# Scala, play - cannot return list from server

Tags: scala, playframework

I have created a simple list getter from rest api:

```
def list: Future[Iterable[ProductResource]] = {
    ProductService.listAllProducts.map { postDataList =>
      postDataList.map(postData => createProductResource(postData))
    }
  }
```

It convert product objects into json with this writer:

```
object ProductResource {
    implicit val implicitWrites = new Writes[Product] {
      def writes(product: Product): JsValue = {
        Json.obj(
          "id" -> product.id,
          "name" -> product.name,
          "description" -> product.description,
          "price" -> product.price,
          "amount" -> product.amount

        )
      }
    }
  }
```

but when I compile project I get: `play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[Cannot use a method returning scala.concurrent.Future[Iterable[controllers.ProductController.ProductResource]] as a Handler for requests]` which I do not understand how to fix it. 
I looked on this tutorial https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/play-rest-api/part-1/index.html
and there is similar list function.

**EDIT:**

I updated this function and add an Action:

```
def list: Action[AnyContent] = {
    Action.async { implicit request =>
      find.map { products =>
        Ok(Json.toJson(products))
      }
    }
  }


  def find: Future[Iterable[ProductResource]] = {
    ProductService.listAllProducts.map { postDataList =>
      postDataList.map(postData => createProductResource(postData))
    }
  }
```

Now I get `No Json serializer found for type Iterable[controllers.ProductController.ProductResource]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.`, but I created a writes.

Answer (score 2):

your controller must return a Future of JsValue (`Future[JsValue]`).
But your are returning Iterable of ProductResource (`Iterable[ProductResource]`).
to convert your Iterable[ProductResource] to JsValue.

- convert each individual ProductResource objects to JsObject
- do a `foldLeft` action to convert the sequence of JsObjects to JsArray.
- make your the implicit JsonWriter that converts `ProductResource` type to JsValue is imported and available in scope. *(The implicitWrites shown in the Question converts Product to a Json. The controller is expecting a JsonWriter for type ProductResource)*

This can be done like the below.

```
import ProductResource.implicitWrites
import play.api.libs.json._

def list: Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { 
        find
         .map(x => Json.toJson(x))
         .map(x => x.foldLeft(JsArray())({case (acc, json) => acc :+ json})) 
         .map(x => Ok(x))
  }
```

Comment: it is method defined in JsArray about. see link below
https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.1/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsArray@:+(el:play.api.libs.json.JsValue):play.api.libs.json.JsArray

Comment: I'm using play 2.4

Comment: @allocer updated my answer. and `:+` method exists in 2.4 as well https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.1/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsArray@:+(el:play.api.libs.json.JsValue):play.api.libs.json.JsArray

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed my change in `ProdcutResource` object

```
case class ProductResource(id: Option[Long], name: String, description: String, price: BigDecimal, amount: Int)

object ProductResource {
  implicit val implicitWrites = new Writes[ProductResource] {
    def writes(product: ProductResource): JsValue = {
      Json.obj(
        "id" -> product.id,
        "name" -> product.name,
        "description" -> product.description,
        "price" -> product.price,
        "amount" -> product.amount

      )
    }
  }
}
```

and no errors connected to json appear.